# How to jump from parent window to child window in pywinauto

Tags: windows, automation

I am trying to automate printer driver setup installation steps. once i click next button it is jumping into small pop up window with OK button, I have to click that button. please help on this.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code that your tried with?

Answer (score 0):

Find the control properties like title, automation_id, control type with the help of print_control_identifiers().